# Conjecture on the unsolvability of the $\{3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times 3\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ dots problem starting from the central point

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, combinatorial-optimization, conjectures

In 2020 (see [Solving the $106$ years old $3^k$ points problem with the clockwise-algorithm](https://doi.org/10.14710/jfma.v3i2.8551), JFMA, 3(2), p. 96), I conjectured that, in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^k$, we can cover any given set of $3^k$ points $\mathcal{H}(3,k):=\{3 \times 3 \times \cdots \times 3\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$  with an optimal polygonal chain $\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right):=\rm{S}_1$-$\rm{S}_2$-$\rm{S}_3$-$\cdots$-$\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right)}$-$\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right)}$ having minimum link-lenght, whose two endpoints belong to $\mathcal{H}(3,k)$, if and only if $$\rm{S}_1 \not\equiv (1,1,\dots,1) \wedge \rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right)} \not\equiv (1,1,\dots,1).$$

I suspect that the above would not be so hard to be proven, since Theorem 1 by [1](https://doi.org/10.14710/jfma.v3i2.8551) and Theorem 2.1 by [Minimum-Link Covering Trails for any Hypercubic Lattice](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.01699.pdf) imply that any optimal covering trail for $\mathcal{H}(3,k)$ has to be a sequence of consecutive (connected) line segments joining $\frac{3^k-3}{2}$ times $2$ unvisited points of $\mathcal{H}(3,k)$ and only one time $3$ new points (no exceptions).

**Conjecture:** For any $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$, there does not exist any $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$ links (optimal) polygonal chain $\mathcal{P}\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right):=\rm{S}_1$-$\rm{S}_2$-$\rm{S}_3$-$\cdots$-$\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right)}$-$\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right)}$ that visits all the points of the set $\mathcal{H}(3,k)$ and such that $\rm{S}_1 \not\equiv (1,1,\dots,1) \wedge \rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right)} \not\equiv (1,1,\dots,1)$.

Now, since we need to start from the central point $C:=(1,1,\dots, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (otherwise, we could simply reverse the chosen sequence of the nodes of $\mathcal{P}$), we observe that the link $\rm{S}_1$-$\rm{S}_2$ visits no more that two points and the same thing must necessarily occur for $\rm{S}_2$-$\rm{S}_3$, but is that true up to $\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k-1}{2}\right)}$-$\rm{S}_{\left(\frac{3^k+1}{2}\right)}$, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$?

Comment: It seems to me that your usage of 3 doesn't work in $\ 3\times3\ldots\times 3.$

Comment: Could you explain me better what do you mean? The number of optimal trails returned by my clockwise-algorithm grows exponentially as $k$ grows and since you can solve the $k=2$ case by starting at any position except from the central point, you can do the same for any $k>2$. As a graphical proof of the 2D case, you can simply take a look at Figure 6 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.08708.pdf . Thus, I can only guess that you are referring to the hypothesis that you can solve the $3 \times 3 \cdots \times 3$ case by starting at $\rm{C}$ for some value of $k>3$. Am I right?

Comment: Are you aware of https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0452? I think it studied the same problem that you investigate in your paper.

Comment: Yes, I was fully aware of that reference, since I've cited it in several preprints/papers (e.g., my recently uploaded https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.01699.pdf lists it as [4] and it is also Reference [14] of the above mentioned https://ejournal2.undip.ac.id/index.php/jfma/article/view/8551/4813). Unfortunately, Keszegh's paper covers only the $k=2$ case and nobody was able to solve even the $k=3$ case under the basic nine-dots problem rules, until Nov. 2020, when I released the aforementioned paper published on JFMA, 3(2), pp. 84-97). Thus, the conjecture on the central point remains unproved.